# Increase worker process memory IIS 7

Tags: c#, iis-7, ssrs-2008, out-of-memory, worker-process

I am trying to render a report and then create a pdf out of it.
But on my production server, when i try to execute this code; I get a system out of memory exception.

After analyzing I found that when this code is executed: the worker process goes almost to 2 gb and at peak point throws exception.

Could any one please help me out in this. I have already optimized the report and database objects. also I dont want to make allocate multiple worker process for this.
I think I may need to increase the memory allocation of worker process, But HOW!!

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to make a few assumptions;

1. You are using Crystal Reports to generate the report for you yes?
2. You have configured your IIS application pools' memory limits to Zero(0)(Meaning they should consume as needed)
3. You are using the latest updated Reporting Objects in your code.
4. If, as in my case, you have been relating these reports to SAP objects or any other COM objects, make sure you dispose of them properly, 
   ie.

`System.Runtime.Interopservices.marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Object o);`

If you could maybe mention what object exactly are taking up such a large amount of memory?
How large is this report?